# Changing an element's className via onClick in React triggers a rerender, but conditional className construction does not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My app is using an array of div elements to display a grid.  The array is stored in Context so other components can access the data but I'm not sure if that matters in this case.  I have an onClick function that changes the CSS class of a clicked-on element, so that it has a colored background.  This works fine, and toggles properly.

I want to remove all selections if the grid is changed to a smaller size.  I tried a few approaches and got some strange behavior as a result, culminating in some very confusing behavior from this code:

```
    selectTile(tilesArray, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let tempArray = [...tilesArray];
        if(event.target.className === "grid-tile"){
            event.target.className = "grid-tileb";
            tempArray.push(event.target.id);
        } else {
            event.target.className = "grid-tile";
            tempArray.splice(tempArray.indexOf(event.target.id),1);
        }
        this.setState({selectedTiles: tempArray})
    }
    makeGrid(x, y, tilesize, visible, hex){
        const gridsDataArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('grids'));
        const index = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGrid'));
        let clearSelection = false;
        if(x < gridsDataArray[index].dims[0] || y < gridsDataArray[index].dims[1]){
            clearSelection = true;
        }
        let columnStr = "";
        let tileArray = [];
        const widthStr = tilesize.toString() + "px"
        if(clearSelection){
            this.setState({selectedTiles:[]})
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                if(i===0) columnStr = columnStr + "auto ";//x loops over columns so this runs once for all columns.
                let div = (
                    <div 
                        id={"x" + j.toString() + "y" + i.toString()}//for example at coordinates 5,6 id is x5y6.  starts at 0.
                        key={"x" + j.toString() + "y" + i.toString()}
                        className={(this.state.selectedTiles.indexOf("x" + j.toString() + "y" + i.toString()) < 0 ? 
                            "grid-tile" : 
                            "grid-tileb")}
                        style={{
                            width: widthStr,
                            height: widthStr,
                            border: "1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0," + (visible ? "0.6)" : "0.0)")
                        }}
                        onClick={(event) => this.selectTile(this.state.selectedTiles, event)}
                    >
                    </div>
                )
                tileArray.push(div);
            }
        }
        let iColumnStr = "";
        for (let i= 0; i < 330/tilesize; i++){
            iColumnStr = iColumnStr + "auto ";
        }
        return {
            columns: columnStr,
            imageColumns: iColumnStr,
            tiles: tileArray,
            name: gridsDataArray[index].name,
            bgurl: gridsDataArray[index].bgurl
        };
    }
```

If I select some tiles, then make the grid smaller, the previously selected tiles remain colored, but the selectedTiles array is empty.  If I change the grid again in any way, the selected tiles lose the coloring.  So okay, maybe that's because setState is async and the conditional statement is using the old state, right?  Well, I tried `className={(clearSelection || this.state.selectedTiles.indexOf("x" + j.toString() + "y" + i.toString()) < 0 ?`  instead and that doesn't work.  In fact, it works LESS-- the selected tiles never lose coloring even after changing the grid twice.  That scenario also happens if I put

```
        if(clearSelection){
            this.setState({selectedTiles:[]})
        }
```

after the for loop instead of before it.  That seems to indicate that it's NOT an async problem, as well.  Plus, if I reduce the dimensions of the grid so that the colored elements are not part of the grid anymore, they're properly removed, and uncolored elements are added once I make the grid bigger again as you'd expect.

Why are my elements not rerendering properly?  I'm not even sure why selectTile triggers a rerender in the first place, since if I remove the setState line from it, it still works.  I don't need any conditional className construction in the for loop, either.

I think I can circumvent this issue entirely by running a loop across the selectedTiles array after(or before) I call makeGrid and directly changing the class names that way instead of from inside makeGrid, but I'd still like to know why this behavior occurs.

edit: Can't change the class names by retrieving from the tile array via the coordinates contained in the selectedTiles array(though the code to do so was fun to figure out); JSX objects don't like to be manipulated directly.  Instead, I ran a loop across selectedTiles and only removed coordinates that were outside the new grid.  If the tiles are outside the grid they are fully reset anyway when the grid is made larger again, so the only leftover data is in selectedTiles.

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example? With React component and the sample data? It's hard to find out what's going on without it. The only thing I know right now, is that selectTile does not cause rerender of your grid

Comment: I feel like that might be a lot of code.  How would I give it to you?  pastebin?
Also, selectTile definitely changes the background color, which happens on rerender, right?  I can comment out the lines that change the className, and it no longer changes the color when I click on tiles, so it's definitely from selectTile.
Lastly, I'm going to sleep so there will be a delay.

Comment: SetState is causing rerender of your component, so when rerender happens, the new state should be already passed to your makeGrid. But in this case, it looks like your divs are not being updated during that rerender but with this code I can't find out what's wrong. Pastebin is fine, but limit it as minimal as you can. I just need functionalities that you described in your question.

Comment: Like I said in my post, removing the setState call from selectTile does not prevent the tiles from being colored.  A rerender is being triggered in some other way.  My guess at this point is the onClick function; it's an arrow function so it's being recreated every time it's called, and it's stored inside the tile array which is part of the state, so maybe that is considered a state change?
pastebin: https://pastebin.com/nJULBmEQ

the folder format should be obvious.  Also uh, I cut out some major stuff and edited index.js, this does not reflect the full functionality of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I found the issue with your code here.

You tried it to make it as state independent as you can, and that caused the issue here.

Firstly, I included your grid metadata to state and assigned it to the starting values from localStorage, so that it is accessible from inside the Grid

```js
    this.state = {
      x: topGridData.dims[0],
      y: topGridData.dims[1],
      tilesize: topGridData.dims[2],
      visible: topGridData.visible,
      hex: topGridData.hex,
      selectedTiles: [],
      ...this.makeGrid(topGridData.dims[0], topGridData.dims[1], topGridData.dims[2],
        topGridData.visible, topGridData.hex)
    };
```

Then I modified your setGrid function, so that it sets grid values as soon as they change

```js
setGrid(x, y, tilesize, visible, hex) {
  this.setState({
    x,
    y,
    tilesize,
    visible,
    hex,
    ...this.makeGrid(x, y, tilesize, visible, hex)
  });
}
```

And now we go for the faulty function that was causing the problem. The problem with this function, was that it was setting className via the DOM, outside React, so React was not able to react (pun not intented) properly to the element change.

So firstly I got rid of these two as they are not needed:

```js
event.target.className = "grid-tileb";
event.target.className = "grid-tile";
```

Then I've attached a callback to a setState, so that Grid is rebuilt properly, everytime your selectedTiles array is changed

```js
this.setState({
  selectedTiles: tempArray
}, () => this.setState(this.makeGrid(this.state.x, this.state.y, this.state.tilesize, this.state.visible, this.state.hex)));
```

And this is how the whole selectTile function looks like:

```js
selectTile(tilesArray, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let tempArray = [...tilesArray];
  if (event.target.className === "grid-tile") {
    tempArray.push(event.target.id);
  } else {
    tempArray.splice(tempArray.indexOf(event.target.id), 1);
  }
  this.setState({
    selectedTiles: tempArray
  }, () => this.setState(this.makeGrid(this.state.x, this.state.y, this.state.tilesize, this.state.visible, this.state.hex)))
}
```

I left your clearing of the state, because it is important here, selectedTiles from state must be cleared

```js
if (clearSelection) {
  this.setState({
    selectedTiles: []
  });
}
```

The last thing that I added is new condition that is actually taken from your original code

```js
className = {
  (clearSelection || this.state.selectedTiles.indexOf("x" + j.toString() + "y" + i.toString()) < 0 ?
    "grid-tile" :
    "grid-tileb")
}
```

And that's all, it works as you originally intented!.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like rebuilding the grid at the end of selectTile is the core addition that makes this work as I originally planned.